# How can I stop Ubuntu from freezing up?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, updates

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 2 or 3 months ago. Everything was running fine -- there were no issues. For the last few weeks I've been having these problems: (While using a browser) first Ubuntu will lag e.g. I will type something into an edit box and it will take several moments for the characters to appear. Immediately following this the tabs on the browser would turn gray, the mouse couldn't be moved and I had to shut the machine down with the power button. (It froze up.)

I say 'would' now because there has been some improvement. I took WinEunuuchs2Unix advice and installed the new Kernel 4.7.2. The whole issue of lagging and freezing seems to happening a bit less frequently now and the browser tabs aren't turning gray.

I installed Grub now (didn't even realize it wasn't installed.) I know I have to pick the last kernel before 16.04 upgrade. How do I do that?

Comment: Clarity has been established and progress is being made on this issue thanks to WinEunuuchs2Unix. Is there a way you could possibly take this off hold?

Comment: If you [edit] your question and replace the rant with a more detailed description of your problems, this will automatically put it in the reopen queue where the community will review it.

Comment: I edited my question and was descriptive as I could be of my problem. Can you take it off of hold now please?

Comment: Great, much better now. Please also add some info about your hardware, especially CPU, RAM and graphics. I'm voting to reopen noe, but this requires multiple votes from the community.

Comment: Max Screen Resolution 1366 x 768 pixels
Processor 2.16 GHz Celeron N2840
RAM 2 GB DDR3
Hard Drive 500 GB SATA
Graphics Coprocessor  Intel Integrated Graphics
Chipset Brand    intel
Card Description  integrated
Wireless Type 802.11bgn

Comment: You would *really* profit from a RAM upgrade. It is no fun below 4GB these days any more, IMHO. If your RAM gets full and the system needs to swap out large amounts onto a slow disk, this could explain the freezes. You should also consider using a more lightweight desktop environment like LXDE (Lubuntu, very light) or XFCE (Xubuntu, light but prettier)

Comment: Why was my last comment removed? I made a brief comment informing  Byte Commander that I was in a lot of pain but would take his suggestions concerning the RAM upgrade and look into the various Ubuntu versions. I use a machine. I am not a machine. And this "closed as unclear what you're asking by edwinksl, Byte Commander, Kevin Bowen, Zacharee1, DK Bose Sep 4 at 1:23''  Seems pretty clear  to me (in its edited version) and was to you, Byte Commander. When did it become unclear?

Comment: Some of you may want to review the Ubuntu Code of Conduct page. http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/conduct ... "Ubuntu is about showing humanity to one another: the word itself captures the spirit of being human."

Comment: I don't know whether or what comment of you got removed, but I voted to close the question back when it was 90% rant and not really a useful question. After that you edited it and as I told you, I voted to reopen. However, since then your question has only received two more reopen votes by other people, but 5 are required IIRC. There's nothing more I personally can do for you at the moment. So what exactly are you expecting from me? By the way, about the Ubuntu "be nice/show humanity" policy, *you* were the one that came here and ranted at first.

Comment: I. I just stated what comment got removed. Read it again. / 2. I'm aware of the sequence of events. / 3. The fact that only 2 more votes were required to re-open the question, and the level of my own compliance and civility are apparent to any who followed the thread, coupled with the fact that it didn't get re-opened, makes me wonder about those who voted it down to begin with (and then wouldn't vote it back up.) and the Ubuntu community as a whole. /  4. You, also, Byte Commander, voted to close the thread.  Again, when did my question become unclear to you? / 5. I started it first? Really?

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: Thnx for un- closing this thread.  Any further input would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to Install Kernel 4.8.4

---

**NOTE:** As of December 25, 2016 the most recent Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.4.0-53 performs extremely well and better than 4.8.4 in most circumstances. Furthermore mainline kernel 4.9.0 is now out with ehanced support for AMDGPU and Intel Skylake amongst other issues. That said 4.4.0-53 on my 3rd Generation Intel CPU performs just as well.

---

As of October 24, 2016, Kernel 4.8.4 is the latest stable Kernel. It's not officially supported by Ubuntu but if your hardware requires the latest kernel to operate properly you have little choice but to install it.

Go to the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel page: [Ubuntu Kernel Mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/).

Scroll down near the bottom and click on `4.8.4`.

Notice the files under AMD64 and how those files names and the main web link is used to build the following commands (which you need type or copy and paste into your terminal):

```
cd /tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.4/linux-headers-4.8.4-040804_4.8.4-040804.201610220733_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.4/linux-headers-4.8.4-040804-generic_4.8.4-040804.201610220733_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.4/linux-image-4.8.4-040804-generic_4.8.4-040804.201610220733_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

Using the Website address and adding in the file name, you complete the entire `wget` command. Study this technique so you can repeat it with any kernel version. We want `amd64` for 64-bit versions of Ubuntu running on Intel and AMD chips. We want `generic` which is the mainstream version of the kernel. `low-latency` on the other hand is difficult to setup and maintain but necessary for those in the sound recording industry and similar industries.

Comment: 1.  I was specific. I stated exactly what was happening.
2. No, wrong, I did not recently upgrade to 16.04. I did that a while ago.

Comment: If you upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 "a while ago" and not "recently" a kernel update might still be at the root of your problems (whatever those are).

Comment: I followed your advice and installed the  new Kernel 4.7.2. I'm seeing an improvement but it's still not quite there yet. I'll try the Grub thing once I find out what it is.



I honestly don't know how to explain the problems I'm having any more specifically than I already have.

1.) My puter starts to lag.. like when I'm typing something and it takes a long time for the characters to appear in the edit box.

2.) The next thing that happens (right after that) is my puter freezes up. The mouse won't move. I can't do anything but shut the puter down with the power button.

Comment: This time you caught me on my 6th beer :). Sorry your performance is substandard but glad 4.7.2 helped. The "grub thing" is only rebooting, selecting "advanced options" and then picking the last kernel before 16.04 upgrade such as 4.1.13 in my case. HTH

Comment: Where do I find "advanced options"? :(

Comment: The first option on the grub menu is your regular kernel, ie most recent. The second option on the grub menu is called "Adavanced options" which leads to a sub menu where you can select from all your previous kernel versions. At least that is what I remember from the last time I booted the system and grub loaded.

Comment: It took me hours to find out grub wasn't installed. lol It is now. Moving ahead. Thnx WinEunuuchs2Unix. Progress is slow but at least its moving. :)

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix, I was sick and in a lot of pain at the time which explains why it took me hours to realize that Grub wasn't installed. Lack of food day after day can have that affect on a person..brain...not working. (I just don't want you to think I'm a complete idiot.) :)

Comment: @thewolfstar. You are a complete idiot.. er no, just  an Ubuntu newb. :)

Comment: Thank you to all wonderful Ubuntu developers but so far, for the last week, at least, all problems have been fixed. Lagging and freezing, admin access, etc. Thank you thank you thank you. Mods please don't remove this comment. It's relevant as problems have been fixed.

Comment: Glad to hear things are working smoothly for you now. If you encounter problems with Kernel 4.7.2 please update to Kernel 4.8.1 which came out a couple of days ago.

Comment: Thnx,  WinEunuuchs2Unix. I think you are some of the coolest beans I've seen around these parts and you have been very helpful. Also @Bytecommander You have been helpful, too, and when I get some pennies together I will purchase some r

Comment: lol some ram. And WinEunuuchs2Unix, I will do the Kernel update if I encounter problems. So far so good. :)

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix I am starting to have the same problems. I tried to install the new Kernel 4.8.1 but I'm having trouble installing it. This is what I get: |||
puter@puter:~$ $ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.1/linux-headers-4.8.1-040801_4.8.1-040801.201610071031_all.deb
$: command not found

Comment: The new kernel is 4.8.4 not 4.8.1. Use it instead.

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thnx

Comment: All I can find is Linux Kernel 4.8-RC3. Is that the same as 4.8.4?

Comment: I just downloaded something that said it was a patch for 4.8.4 and then clicked extract. I got a mssg back that said extract successful. Is there something else I need to do now?

Comment: @thewolfstar Instructions for downloading Kernel 4.8.4 are in the answer. If you don't mind I'd like to edit your question to reflect the new answer.

Comment: Okay, you can edit the question, if you like.

Comment: lol I didn't realize that you had put the instructions up there. I just copied and pasta'd into the terminal and it's working away right now -- doing something! :)

Comment: It stopped. I guess I have to reboot now.

Comment: What is your computer make and model?

Comment: It's still installing. Sry. Dell Inspiron 64 bit laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47363/discussion-between-wineunuuchs2unix-and-thewolfstar).

Answer (score 2):

Check your RAM.  If you have less than 4 gb.  Ubuntu is not your best choice and it is an easy reason for locking up.
**Lubuntu, Xubuntu or Mate** will run much better on 2gb.

Doing a fresh install instead of an upgrade is always the recommended action.  It does not take long to reinstall all of your applications.  In the end, it will be better and take less time.

You might want to see if you have virtual memory.  If not, you should look up how to do so.  If you are going to do a fresh install, make sure you have 1 or 2 gb available as a partition ready for swap.
The install program should pick it automatically, if not, you should do the advanced install and select that drive for virtual memory.

Comment: Ok, just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, which is what I started with and which never gave me any problems. I need to get at least 2 more gigs of ram which I will real soon. Thnx for your response, Bhikkhu Subhuti.

Comment: I have a question. I was gone for a while. I had 20 reputation points when I was here last. How did it go down to 15 points?

Comment: Someone downvoted your question.  It could be that the new version of Ubuntu takes more RAM..  They usually take more ram with each version.  I would go with Mate 16.04 if I were you.  I ran it for a long time.  It was quick and well supported.  Worked well when I had 2gb.  Now I have 8 and use Gnome which might be the best looking distro.  (using the included global dark theme in the tweak..)

Comment: I'm just gonna get more ram. No, my reputation went from 5-18 and then to 20 the next day after that original post. It's a long story. I was gone and just came back and it went down to 15 before I typed anything new. Any mods know anything about this?